# Recent posts in footer widget not aligning

Tags: css

My site [website](http://www.20watt.nl) uses wordpress (folio theme) with 3 footer widgets. The first 2 footer widgets are okay and align as they should.

The 3rd one displays my "recent posts" (called "blog & recente opdrachten"), but the list of recent posts does not align correctly to the left - seems to be aligned to the right or centre.

I've gone through the styles.css and footer.php, but can not seem to find anything to fix it.

Any help is much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the following style:

```
ul {
margin-left: 48px;
margin-left: 3rem;
}
```

Adding the following style should fix your problem:

```
.footer-widget ul {
margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this in style

```
.footer-widget ul{
margin:0px;
}
```